# Slightly confused about reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, lost-reputation

I think this is the right place to post this.

I had about 100 reputation, and this morning I came on to answer some questions and now have 1.

How on earth did I lose so much rep? as far as I am aware I had done nothing wrong, just asked a question the previous day.

Many thanks for information,

Comment: For flagged posts neither the -100 nor the deletion can be reversed without moderator intervention. As you seem to have found an answer I would advise against asking to have the question reinstated. Also, we try to keep the site suitable for automated nanny software: don't want folks to lose access to SO at work when the automatic filter detects "dirty" words, 'ya know...

Answer (score 4):

Check this, it should explain exactly how your reputation breaks down:
https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

If it shows more reputation, flag one of your posts and ask for a reputation recalc.

The most likely reason to drop 100 point is if you had a post flagged as span or offensive by 5 users.

Comment: I have a "12  2794373 (-100)", presume it must have been a down voted posts. Thats annoying, it was voted down because I was sharing my source, some of which was obfuscated. Anyway, thanks for your time!

Comment: The leading `12` means *"spam"* - i.e. your post got flagged as spam as Kobi suspected. @pez

Comment: It was [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794373/php-gd-gradient-text) (10k only). I am not sure why it was flagged. The final version was fine.

Comment: The edit history is a mess. Presumable the final vote was cast by a user who had not refreshed the question to see the last round of improvement...

Comment: @dmckee What? 6 hours later? There was one thing worthy of the flag in there and that was edited out **2 weeks** ago

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this post was flagged as offensive by 6 other users and auto-deleted. This causes a -100 rep penalty as well.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794373

Comment: I don't understand how it was offensive, oh well. Not much I can do, just seems a shame to lose that much rep!